# Pegar o resultado do ng-repeat e usar no moment.js

Tags: html, angularjs

Tenho uma aplicação que utiliza um `ng-repeat` para listar informações. Uma dessas informações vem com uma data como exemplo abaixo, o que acontece é que eu queria usar a função relativa do `moment.Js`. A minha dificuldade é pegar esse valor recebido e usar nos parâmetros certo do `moment.js`.

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
        <td>
            {{ x.TempoEspera }} 
        </td> 
    </tr>                                               
</tbody>
```

> valor recebido= "TempoEspera":"11/13/2014 17:17:47"

Comment: leozado você quer formatar sua data em um formato especifico?

Comment: sim, gostaria que ela não retorna-se essa data 'BRUTA' e sim neste seguinte formato por exemplo. 
1 minutos atras ou 10 horas atras.

Comment: Você quer mostrar o tempo decorrido da data informada até agora?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode fazer um filtro que receba a data e a formate como desejar:

```js
angular.module("app", []);

angular.module('app').controller("myctrl", function() {
  
  var ctrl = this;
  ctrl.names = [{tempoEspera: "2015-01-01T01:00:00"}, {tempoEspera: "2016-01-01T23:00:59"}]

});

// cria um filtro que receba uma data e formata-a atraves do momentjs
angular.module('app').filter('formatarData', function() {
  return function(input) {

    if (!input) {
      return '';
    }

    return moment(input).format("LLLL"); // formata conforme a localização do utilizador. Alterar esta linha para alterar a forma como a data e formatada.
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myctrl as ctrl">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Test</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="x in ctrl.names">
        <!--A cada iteração do ng-repeat, o filtro formatarData e aplicado ao conteudo da variavel x.TempoEspera -->
        <td>{{x.tempoEspera | formatarData}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

No exemplo atrás, e declarado um filtro chamado `formatarData` que recebe uma string que representa uma data e formata-a usando o `momentjs`.

Neste caso especifico, esta a formatar a data com o formato [`LLLL` - Month name, day of month, day of week, year, time](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/).

No entanto, pode alterar o codigo do filtro para formatar a data para o formato que precisar.

Comment: certo, mas ali voce recebe o valor de uma variável e como eu conseguiria filtrar o valor que vem de um outro lugar que no caso foi declarado dessa forma:



var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

 app.controller('customersCtrl2', function($scope, $http, $ctrl) {
       $http.get("http://192.168.0.235:8037/webrun/FluxoWEB002.rule?sys=EXP")
    .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.pedidos;});
    
   });

Comment: O valor {TempoEspera: "2000-01-01T01:00:00"} vem dessa pagina "http://192.168.0.235:8037/webrun/FluxoWEB002.rule?sys=EXP", junto com outras informações, e eu precisaria formatar apenas o valor TempoEspera.

Comment: nao sei se entendi, da forma como mostra, continua a funcionar desde que o `$scope.names` tenha objectos que por sua vez tenham a propriedade `TempoEspera`.

Comment: Quando vem outras informaçoes que não é data ele retorna isso 
{ Invalid date}

Comment: Nossa eu estava tão focado que nos teste que estava fazendo acabei cabaçando.

Comment: estava retorando invalid data porque mantive os filtros nas outras chamadas nos teste que estava fazendo através do seu código, porem quando vou usar o filtro na minha aplicação ele não funciona corretamente teria como me ajudar a consertar o filtro para que ele funciona- se apartir desse codigo

var app = angular.module('myApp', []); app.controller('customersCtrl2', function($scope, $http, $ctrl) { $http.get("192.168.0.235:8037/webrun/FluxoWEB002.rule?sys=EXP") .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.pedidos;}); });

Comment: tem de registrar o filtro antes de o pode usar no HTML, veja a linha `angular.module('app').filter('formatarData', function() ` do codigo da resposta.

Comment: consegui, muito obrigado